# Service restart after calling startService

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm starting a service using MainActivity. And a BroadcastReceiver is attached to my application. In that class, I have written the following code to start my service when phone is connected to internet.

```
private void doUploading(Context context) {
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean(Flags.KEY.PHONE_IS_ONLINE_KEY, true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    intent.setAction(Flags.ACTION.SEND_UPDATE_COMMAND_ACTION);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

In LocationService class I have overwritten onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method. When BroadcastReceiver start the service the following code begins to execute.

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Flags.ACTION.SEND_UPDATE_COMMAND_ACTION)) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras.getBoolean(Flags.KEY.PHONE_IS_ONLINE_KEY)) {
                upload();
            }
}
```

This code work fine when I run this application's apk in my phone. But I have found the following error.

Disconnect phone from internet. I run the application. Start the LocationService. Then kill the activity. (Remove it from Recent Apps also). Now LocationService is still running.(I have verified it by debugging). Then connect phone to internet. BroadcastReceiver execute its code as expected. But then LocationService restarting.(Restart from the begin. That means from onCreate() function) I can't figure out why is this happening.. Please help..!

Thanks..!!

Comment: This usually happens when there is an exception in the service. Check out service's log.

Comment: post the errors from the logcat